# UIImageView error with OCUnit

Tags: objective-c, ios, unit-testing, ocunit

am using OCUnit to test my application however am running into some trouble. When I attempt to include a class that contains an instance variable of type UIImageView, I get the following error: "Expected specifier-qualifier-list before UIImageView"

My declaration code is:

```
UIImageView *_icon;
```

I can't work out whats causing this and it only happens when I attempt to build my application using my test target.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test target doesn't know what UIImageView is. It needs its own precompiled-header referencing UIKit (or you could import UIKit in that file), and it needs to link that framework.

Comment: thanks that worked, I imported UIKit in the file that I declare that _icon in. Does this mean that when I run using the "normal" target that UIkit will be imported twice into that class?

Comment: Nope. I believe #import prevents importing twice. #include does not.

Comment: thanks again. Just one final question the "normal" target has a *_Prefix.pch file that imports UIKit automatically to all class file. Does the "test" target have its own version?

Comment: It certainly _can_. I'm not sure off the top of my head how it works in Xcode 3, and I don't have my Mac handy. I do know that in Xcode 4, creating a new test bundle or creates the new PCH for you. You should be able to edit the target or bundle to reference its own PCH somehow.